# How to direct scroll input to ScrollView? [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollview

What I'm trying to accomplish is sending the scrolling input from elsewhere in a canvas [Purple], to the ScrollView in the center of the canvas [Red]. While of course keeping the default input area for scrolling inside the ScrollView [Green]. The diagram image below is pretty self explanatory.[image]

Comment: Have you tried, do you have any code that you could share? The point of SO is to help users find/fix problems or point them in the right direction, but not create solutions from scratch based on a concept.

Comment: What ScrollView do You use? Built From Unity.UI? Scroll Input should be based on UI colliders. So all You gonna do is change collider size to fit desired area.

Comment: @selezen88 You were right. To achieve it, I basically just had to expand the outer ScrollView and the inner 'Viewport' to the full width of the screen, and give the inner 'Content' a prefered width so it stays the same size. So its like in that diagram if the red and green boxes extended the entire width, but the content inside stayed the original box shape, which is what I wanted. I hadnt considered this because of the convoluted nested layout groups I had making up the ScrollView.

Comment: @Bloumbs, Glad it helped, have a good day